# .class error when I'm pretty sure the array is correctly defined

Tags: java, arrays

Tester class:

```
public class StoreTester
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Store DarthV = new Store("Darth Vader Costume", 2, 1956, 29.99);
    Store HanS = new Store("Han Solo Costume", 6, 2856, 15.99);
    Store gLightsaber = new Store("Green Light Saber", 7, 8234, 5.99);
    Store bLightsaber = new Store("Blue Light Saber", 10, 8235, 5.99);
    Store rLightsaber = new Store("Red Light Saber", 4, 8233, 5.99);
    Store StormTroop = new Store("Storm Trooper Costume", 2, 1955, 25.99);
    Store DarthM = new Store("Darth Mual Costume", 4, 1957, 28.99);
    Store R2D2 = new Store("R2D2 Plush", 6, 1238, 12.99);
    Store C3PO = new Store("C3PO Plush", 4, 1240, 16.99);
    Store KyloR = new Store("Kylo Ren Costume", 2, 1960,  
    Store[] items = new Store[]{ DarthV, HanS, gLightsaber, bLightsaber, rLightsaber, StormTroop, DarthM, R2D2, C3PO, KyloR};
}
}
```

Store class:

```
public class Store
{
//instance variables
private int quantity; 
private int productNum;
private double price;
private String name;

//Constructor for objects of class Store
public Store(String name, int quantity, int productNum, double price){
    this.name = name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.productNum = productNum;
    this.price = price;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public int getQuantity(){
    return quantity;
}

public int getProductNum(){
    return productNum;
}

public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}

public String toString(){
    String string = String.format("%-30s %4d %-20d %3.2f", name, quantity, productNum, price);
    return string;
}
}
```

This has never happened to me before when initializing an array with objects like this. For some reason I am getting a "'.class' expected" error even though I'm pretty sure that I initialized the array correctly. Can someone help me find out why i'm getting this error when i've never gotten it before? The error occurs on the very last line of code in the tester class.

Comment: Thats a syntax error no `new Store("Kylo Ren Costume", 2, 1960,`

Comment: Can you include the exact error, and what line it's on?

Comment: Yes I did, check the updated post at the very end

Comment: Please include the exact error where it states the error code, not just telling us where it occurs. It makes it easier for us to help when we know exactly what the IDE is saying rather than what the user is telling us because the user is more than likely to tell us wrong.

Comment: Also side note, when not just return the `String.format(...)` instead of creating a new variable (taking up time and memory) and then returning it on the next line of code?

Comment: updated again, error is: "'.class' expected" error

Comment: Have you checked the syntax error pointed out by @Blasanka? When I fixed that I got no error.

Comment: Ah that fixed it. That's odd though, I don't know why it didn't show up on that line